# XNA GameDefaults Class Settings

Tags: xna, c#, game-mechanics

Are items such as the `GameDifficulty` enum, game settings, and other things in the `GameDefaults` class used for a lot? If so, is there a way to edit them or anything of the sorts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings ([all of `GameDefaults`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.gamedefaults_members%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx)) are used to describe a specific set of profile information from Xbox live.  You can use them as you see fit.  If your game supports any similar configuration options, you can employ this information to make a slightly better educated guess about a player's choices in your game.  They are not required, or reliable, in any way.

There is no editing these properties.  As you can see from the documentation, they are all read-only.

If you are developing for XBLIG, and your game even has useful configuration options, you are making a rare effort to add quality to your game.  Making defaults that pay attention to these settings is...really special.  (No, they don't get used a lot.)

Comment: So I could instead of using them, make my own version of them, and use that, and it would actually be better since it'd be more customized to the game?

Comment: Yes, and that is really your only option.  Even if you tried to tap these settings directly, you would still need some custom set of default settings.  You can read that class to alter your own defaults, but you still need to create a custom settings container.